# How to clear controls i.e. TextBoxes, ComboBoxes, CheckBoxes etc. inside a panel control in C#

Tags: checkbox, combobox, textbox, panel

I have a form with TextBoxes, ComboBoxes, CheckBoxes, DataGridView inside a panel.  On a Button Click event I have the following procedure to clear the controls:

```
public void ClearControlValues(Control Container)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (Control ctrl in Container.Controls)
            {
                if (ctrl.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
                {
                    ((TextBox)ctrl).Text = "";
                }

                if (ctrl.GetType() == typeof(ComboBox))
                {
                    ((ComboBox)ctrl).SelectedIndex = -1;
                }

                if (ctrl.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox))
                {
                    ((CheckBox)ctrl).Checked = false;
                }

                if (ctrl.GetType() == typeof(DateTimePicker))
                {
                    ((DateTimePicker)ctrl).Text = "";
                }

                if (ctrl.GetType() == typeof(DataGrid))
                {
                    ((DateTimePicker)ctrl).Text = "";
                }

                if (ctrl.Controls.Count > 0)
                {
                    LockControlValues(ctrl);
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Button Click calling:

```
ClearControlValues(this);
```

But:
Controls inside my panel "MainPanel" is not clearing. What do I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

This code solve the problem:

```
public void ClearControlValues(Control Container)
    {

        foreach (Control c in Container.Controls)
        {
            if (c is CheckBox)
            {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)c;
                cb.Checked = false;
            }

            if (c is TextBox)
            {
                TextBox tb = (TextBox)c;
                tb.Text = "";
            }

            if (c is ComboBox)
            {
                ComboBox cb = (ComboBox)c;
                cb.SelectedIndex = -1;
            }

            if (c is DateTimePicker)
            {
                DateTimePicker dtp = (DateTimePicker)c;
                dtp.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString();
            }

            if (c is DataGridView)
            {
                DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)c;
                dgv.Rows.Clear();
                dgv.Refresh();

            }
        }


    }
```

Calling:

```
ClearControlValues(MainPanel);
```

Thank you,